# Hub site vs subsite

Tags: sharepoint-online, sub-site, hub-site, sharing

I have a team site with a subsite.

Now I want the lists in the team site to be visible in the subsite?

It must work with a hub site?

Answer (score 1):

Both in hub site or subsite, we can use [Highlighted content web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-highlighted-content-web-part-e34199b0-ff1a-47fb-8f4d-dbcaed329efd) to display lists via **custom query** from other sites as shown below:

[image]

Similar issue for your reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/57439/display-list-from-another-site-collection.html